# Regex for no digit at the end and the beginning of a string

Tags: regex

I've been searching for a Regex to match a string that has no digit at the end and the beginning. Since this is a password complexity requirement I have to implement, I thought that there would be at least one example for this use case, but I couldn't find anything like that. Also my own attempts were not successful to create such a Regex.

Examples

```
abc2 - no match
1bca - no match
bac  - match
b1b1 - no match
b1b  - match
1c1c - no match
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What OS and program are you using to build the regex in? Show the attempts you made.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Win8.1, so far I only cam up with things like this: ^\D.\D$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

but just remember that this regex will require input to be at least 2 characters length.

To match characters other than just alpha-numerals you can use:

You can use:

```
/^\D.*?\D$/gm
```

[Regexr Demo](http://regexr.com/3bgi4)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I applied this to regexr.com and my example strings and it doesn't seem to match anything like that, http://regexr.com/3bghu. Also please keep in mind, that the other requirements are in separate regexes, just so I can keep my sanity. There are other characters than a-z and A-Z that can appear at the beeginning.

Comment: Great! That one seems to work. Thanks a lot. Just wondering about the m flag, why do I need this? Just because I have a multiline text in Regexr?

Comment: Yes `m` is needed when we use anchors `^` and `$` in a multiline text.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but apparently it doesn't work 100%, e.g. "ab2b222ed2" still seems to be matched, or am I reading this wrong? http://regexr.com/3bgi7

Comment: No that won't match. Check this: http://regexr.com/3bgid  It was due to newline after `ab2b222ed2`

Comment: Perfect, that was it :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works:

```
^\D\w*\D$
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. Also what is considered a word? Does it also consider special characters? There can be anything in between.

Comment: @w.d \d is subset of \w, so it is not needed :)